# getResourceAsStream() works fine in eclipse but fails in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, classloader

My (maven)-project looks like this:

```
+ scr/main
++ java
+++ myPackage
++++ MyClass.java
++ resources
+++ python
++++ PythonScript.py
```

I now try to load the py-script to my java class like this:

```
String s = File.separator;
ClassLoader cl = myClass.getClass().getClassLoader();
cl.getResourceAsStream(s + "python" + s + "PythonScript.py"));
```

That works perfectly fine, when excecuted in Eclipse.
However, when I try to do that in a jar file, all I get is NULL...

My jar file looks like this:

```
+ MyJar.jar
++ python
+++ PythonScript.py
```

Comment: How are you packaging jar? Don't you have the source files in the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.separator` in windows is `\\`, so it won't work when trying to get a resource in jar file. Using `"/"` will work both in eclipse and in jar.

```
String s = "/"; //File.separator;
ClassLoader cl = myClass.getClass().getClassLoader();
cl.getResourceAsStream("python" + s + "PythonScript.py"));
```